# Facebook login failure using Angular, and Google Firebase - URL Blocked

Tags: angular, firebase, facebook-login

I am developing a [basic web app](https://political-monitor.firebaseapp.com/login) to measure some political popularity. To get correct polls, we gonna need to authenticate users with their social media accounts such as Facebook, Twitter, and Google accounts.

I have selected Angular as my front-end technology which sits on [Google Firebase platform](https://firebase.google.com/) which come to following [this instruction](https://www.positronx.io/firebase-facebook-login-auth-provider-work-with-angular/) to make authentications.

For Firebase Facebook Login Auth Provider Service (`auth.service.ts`)

```
@Injectable({
   providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {

  constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, // Inject Firebase auth service
) { }

// Sign in with Facebook
FacebookAuth() {
   return this.AuthLogin(new auth.FacebookAuthProvider());
}  

// Auth logic to run auth providers
AuthLogin(provider) {
   return this.afAuth.auth.signInWithPopup(provider)
     .then((result) => {
         console.log('You have been successfully logged in!')
     }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
    })
   }
}
```

for the singin component codes is as simple as following

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from "../../shared/services/auth.service";

@Component({
   selector: 'app-sign-in',
   templateUrl: './sign-in.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./sign-in.component.css']
})

export class SignInComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(public authService: AuthService) { }
   ngOnInit() { }
```

}

HTML codes for `singin components`

```
<!-- Calling FacebookAuth Api from AuthService -->
<div class="formGroup">
   <button type="button" (click)="authService.FacebookAuth()">
      Log in with Facebook
   </button>
</div>
```

Here is configuration on Facebook for developer. `App ID`, and `App Secret` are put in Firebase to make the connection between two.

I facebook login > settings : `client Oauth login`, `web OAuth login` are on
and and added these URLs for redirect.

[image]

and at settings > Basics
[image]

What am I missing to get ride of following error?

URL Blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not whitelisted in the app’s Client OAuth Settings. Make sure Client and Web OAuth Login are on and add all your app domains as Valid OAuth Redirect URIs.

BTW app is working on Google login, you can see that redirect URL is `https://political-monitor.firebaseapp.com/profile`

[image]

update:

- removed after comma URL, and site URL is only `https://political-monitor.firebaseapp.com/` (not working yet)
- redirect URL is only `https://political-monitor.firebaseapp.com/profile` (not working yet)
- Thanks to Venkatesh on the first response below. I took the redirect URL from Firebase and I put it in Facebook setting. URL blocked message is gone. One more progress is needed to resolve this issue in console `Error getting access token from facebook.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: https://political-monitor.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler`

Comment: Remove everything thing after comma(,) used in site URL. Define valid URL for site as well redirect URL.

Comment: @RahulGupta: hi. I applied your recommendation.  Still not working :/

Comment: @RahulGupta: for redirect URL, I am assuming it is either `https://political-monitor.firebaseapp.com/profile` or the long one on the top of pop up. I have them both there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://big-data-privacy.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler

Goto firebase console enable Facebook login then

You have to configure firebase authcall back in Facebook oauth redirect urls

Comment: any idea on why there is console error of Error getting access token from facebook.com, OAuth2 redirect uri is: https://political-monitor.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler

Answer (score 0):

```
Angular + Firebase + Facebook Sign Up integration i did by following steps below:-
```

[image]

```
In Facebook/Meta Developer Page try to follow some points as shown in above image like:-

Client OAuth Login ==> on YES !!

Web OAuth Login ==> on YES !!

Valid OAuth Redirect URIs ==> firebase provide url !!
(as shown below)
```

[image]